# Resetting cursor property to "grab" doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div for which I set:

```
#my_div {
   cursor: grab;
}
```

In a javascript callback I change the cursor property:

```
$("#my_div").css({"cursor": "move"});
```

and the cursor changes properly. When another js function resets it to its original value:

```
$("#my_div").css({"cursor": "grab"});
```

the cursor doesn't change accordingly.
In Firefox, everything works fine.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on fiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome Requires -webkit- before the "grab" name;

```
#my_div {
   cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab; // for chrome
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For chrome have to write webkit CSS.

```
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-cursor-styles/